# If $f(x+1) = x^2 + 3x +5$, then find $f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

A challenge problem from precalc class. I don't know what to do with the one from $f(x+1)$, it doesn't factor well, I could do completing the square but then how do I find $f(x)$? Just stuck on this.

Comment: Hint: $f((x-1)+1)=...$

Comment: @dxiv i don't understand, how can you substitute x for x-1 if you don't know that x is equal to? Is the difference from f(x+1) and f(x-1) +5 and -5?

Comment: The premise holds for $\forall x$. I posted a separate answer to hopefully eliminate any confusion about variable names. Remember that "$f(x) = x$" is the same function as "$f(u) = u$" or "$f(\cdot) = \cdot$".

Comment: Use $x \mapsto x-1$. Why, because $x-1$ is the inverse of $x+1$, using this substitution $x+1$ turns into $x$.

Answer (score 4):

### Hint:

$$f(x+1)=x^2+3x+5=(x+1)^2+(x+1)+3$$

Answer (score 4):

With the substitution $x = u - 1$ the given identity translates to:

$$f((u-1) + 1) = (u-1)^2 + 3 (u-1) + 5$$

$$f(u) = u^2 -2 u + 1 + 3 u - 3 + 5 = u^2 + u + 3$$

Since the name of the variable is inconsequential in the definition of a function, this is the same as:

$$f(x) = x^2 + x + 3$$

Answer (score 1):

Just to be different.

$$f(x+1) = x^2 + 3x + 5$$

\begin{align}
   f(x) - f(x+1)
   &= f((x-1)+1) - f(x) \\
   &= (x-1)^2 + 3(x-1) + 5) - (x^2 + 3x + 5) \\
   &= ((x-1)^2 - x^2) + (3(x-1) - 3x) + (5-5) \\
   &= (x-1-x)(x-1+x) - 3\\
   &= (-1)(2x-1) - 3 \\
   &= -2x - 2
\end{align}

So $f(x) = f(x+1) - 2x - 2 = x^2 + x + 3$

### proof by induction

It is not unreasonable to suppose that $f(x) = x^2 + ax + b$ for some real numbers $a$ and $b$. We can use inductive reasoning to prove that this is the case and to find the values of $a$ and $b$ at the same time.

Our hypothesis will be $f(x) = x^2 + ax + b$ for some real numbers $a$ and $b$.

$f(0) = f(-1+1) = (-1)^2 + 3(-1) + 5 = 3$
By our hypothesis, $f(0) = b$. Hence $b = 3$

So our hypothesis is now $f(x) = x^2 + ax + 3$

Again, by our hypothesis, $f(x+1) = (x+1)^2 + a(x+1) + 3$
Hence
\begin{align}
   x^2 + 3x + 5 &= (x+1)^2 + a(x+1) + 3 \\
   x^2 + 3x + 5 &= (x^2+2x+1) + (ax + a) + 3 \\
   x^2 + 3x + 5 &= x^2 + (2 + a)x + (a + 4) \\
\end{align}

And we see that this is true when $a = 1$.

Hence, by mathematical induction,  $f(x) = x^2 + x + 3$.

Now that I look at this, I realize that I have only shown that $f(n) = n^2 + n + 3$ for $n = 0, 1, 2, \dots$. It is true however that three points uniquely determine a parabola. And we have agreement at an infinite number of points. So this is still a proof.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2+3x+5=x^2+2x+1+x+4=(x+1)^2+x+4=(x+1)^2+(x+1)+3$

So $f(x)=x^2+x+3$

Answer (score 0):

Just ask yourself "What are the operations that I need to perform on $x+1$ to get $x^2+3x+5$?".

$$\begin{align}
f(x+1) &= x^2 + 3x +5\\
&= ((x+1) - 1)^2 + 3((x+1)-1) +5\\
\end{align}$$

Now, suppose that $u = x+1$, then
$$f(u) = (u-1)^2 +3(u-1)+5 = u^2+u+3$$

Evaluating $f$, instead, at $x$, we have
$$f(x) = x^2+x+3$$